# TypeError when calling document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

the following code should display the word Test...but instead the message TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is displayed.
I can't figure out why:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Testtree</title>
  </head>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("kaptree").innerHTML="TEST";
  </script>
  <body>
     <div id="kaptree"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to open my eyes?

Comment: The executing order ...

Comment: put <script>...</script> inside <head> block, it works!

Comment: @DanieleFois No, that won't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/38w9f6zx/ it works...

Comment: @DanieleFois Check the load type in the settings for that fiddle. It's running that code in the OnLoad event, not from the <head>. [This is what happens when putting the code in the <head>](https://jsfiddle.net/qhvwyrez/1/).

Comment: the answer of sveta is correct

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to access the `kaptree` element before it's loaded. Run your script **after** loading the DOM.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Testtree</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="kaptree"></div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("kaptree").innerHTML = "TEST";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should place your scripts after your html elements.

Answer (score 2):

The element with the id "kaptree" is not available at this place. Move the script block below the body and it works.

Otherwise you have to wait for the document-ready state.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is defined before the element that you try to reference.

Move it after :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Testtree</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="kaptree"></div>
  </body>
   <script>
    document.getElementById("kaptree").innerHTML="TEST";
  </script>
</html>
```

Or more readable and maintainable solution, use a function :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Testtree</title>
     <script>
           function changeValue(){
               document.getElementById('kaptree').innerHTML='TEST';
            }
     </script>      
  </head>
  <body>    
     <div id="kaptree"></div>
    <script>changeValue()</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: :O  No!   The onload event is appropriate almost 0% of the time.  So many situations the onload event will fire too late, if at all.  Also, the `<script>` element should be either in the `<body>` or the `<head>` and not in limbo.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski I didn't know it. I will edit to improve it.

Comment: I edited with a function. There is maybe better solutions. I don't get that you mean by "the `<script>` should be in the body". It doesn't work for me. Can you give me a link about it or better doing an answer if it addresses better the problem than the actual responses ?

Comment: Just validate the HTML (https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)  The only children of the <html> element are <head> and <body>, so the <script> element needs to be inside one of those.  If the validator encounters any other element before the <head> it will assume the <body> element is absent and that every element is inside an imaginary <body>.  Using web-based environments (codepen, jsfiddle) will probably occlude most errors of this nature, they don't expect your HTML samples to be complete documents.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski I get your point. Thank you very much for the explanations. I don't do often JavaScript sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the body section with the DIV setup to the top it works.

It runs sequentially so it can't assign the inner.html before the DIV is defined

Answer (score 1):

Because your JS code is called before HTML.

**Solution 1:** Add JS right before `</body>` tag

**Example:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Testtree</title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="kaptree"></div>
  </body>
    <script>

    document.getElementById("kaptree").innerHTML+="TEST";
  </script>
</html>
```

**Solution 2:** Execute JS code inside `window.load` function

**Example:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Testtree</title>
    
    <script>
    window.onload = (function(){
      document.getElementById("kaptree").innerHTML+="TEST";
    });
    
  </script>
  
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="kaptree"></div>
  </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A. Put the script inside head or body.

B. Either put the script after #kaptree, or add a document ready statement. You try to call something that isn't there yet.

```
        <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Testtree</title>
      <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
          document.getElementById("kaptree").innerHTML="TEST";
        }, false);
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div id="kaptree"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Running the script from the head [will not work.](https://jsfiddle.net/qhvwyrez/1/)

Comment: `Put the script inside head or body.` are you sure ?

Comment: [Here is your exact code running as you wrote it.](https://plnkr.co/edit/L1A6S2Hhj2t8aN3shKC2?p=preview) It doesn't work. The code must run **after** the element is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, changed the code to work with an event listener that listens to when the DOM is ready. Now it can work in the head as well.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the solution is so simple.

I will put the function call into a:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```